# form calculation JS (radio)

Tags: javascript, html

the HTML part , just a slice from my code:

```
    <ul>
        <li>HP:<input type="text" id="hp" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
        <li>SP:<input type="text" id="sp" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
        <li>EA:<input type="text" id="ea" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
        <li>ED:<input type="text" id="ed" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
        <li>PA:<input type="text" id="pa" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
        <li>PD:<input type="text" id="pd" size="3" maxlength="3"> </li>
    </ul>
<div class="train">
    <h3>Add Trainer:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>HP:<input type="radio" name="at" id="ahp"></li>
        <li>SP:<input type="radio" name="at" id="asp"></li>
        <li>EA:<input type="radio" name="at" id="aea"></li>
        <li>ED:<input type="radio" name="at" id="aed"></li>
        <li>PA:<input type="radio" name="at" id="apa"></li>
        <li>PD:<input type="radio" name="at" id="apd"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JS:(Where the problem is)

```
function trener1() {
  var test1 = document.getElementById('ahp').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.hp.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test1) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.hp.value = xSum;
};

function trener2() {
  var test2 = document.getElementById('asp').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.sp.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test2) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.sp.value = xSum;
};

function trener3() {
  var test3 = document.getElementById('aea').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.ea.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test3) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.ea.value = xSum;
};

function trener4() {
  var test4 = document.getElementById('aed').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.ed.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test3) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.ed.value = xSum;
};

function trener5() {
  var test5 = document.getElementById('apa').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.pa.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test5) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.pa.value = xSum;
};

function trener6() {
  var test6 = document.getElementById('apd').checked,
    x = Number(document.form.pd.value),
    xSum = 0;
  if (test6) {
    xSum = x + x * 0.1;
  } else {
    xSum = x - x * 0.1;
  }
  document.form.pd.value = xSum;
};
```

So yeah the problem is that it won't subtract the value that has been added if i change my option which it should.. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
document.form.ea.value
```

must be

```
document.forms.formName.ea.value
```

You forgot to specify the name of the form. It should also be `document.forms`.

Also try to optimise you code, something like this should work instead of all these repeating functions:

```
var radio = document.getElementsByName('at');

for (var i = radio.length; i--;) {
    radio[i].onchange = function () {
        var field = document.getElementById(this.id.substr(1)),
            x = Number(field.value),
            xSum = 0;
        if (this.checked) {
            xSum = x + x * 0.1;
        } else {
            xSum = x - x * 0.1;
        }
        field.value = xSum;
    };
}
```

And remove `onclick` handler:

```
<li>SP:<input type="radio" name="at" id="asp"></li>
...
```

Comment: i made a edit , to give more html :) because this way it won't work, also a pic of the thing:http://i.imgur.com/5ZbvBKy.png

Comment: wait i think i explained bad , i want to choose one of the radio-buttons then a value of +10% will be added to one of the textboxses , but if i change the radio-button (i check another) the value should be subtracted and added to the new checkbox but the 10% from that value.

Comment: Right, I got it, will fix it.

Comment: that's how it should work , but the user would enter a value :/ sorry for being so boring :/